# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

In Android Studio 3.6

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath "com.jaredsburrows:gradle-license-plugin:0.8.41"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                fabricApiKey: keystoreProperties['FabricApiKey'] != null
                        ? keystoreProperties['FabricApiKey']
                        : ""
        ]
        multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-keep.txt')
    }
```

But when build I get error:

```
> Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug

> Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
```

Comment: I have a question: why are you adding dependencies in the project gradle file using **classpath** instead of adding them in your app module gradle file using **implementation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
compilsdkVersion 29  
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 29
```